# is it possable to prevent PHP $var from reseting?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im fairly new to PHP and I'm currently working on a battle system, kind of like an idle clicker game, and not sure how to handle somethings do to lack of knowledge. What i am attempting right now is a player clicks a button , that POSTs Attack, and the damaged is taken from enemy hp, but what going on is every time i submit the attack, the HP get reset which is to be expected from PHP, I just don't know how avoid it resetting without having the value stored in a database which im trying to avoid just to keep the work load on the server light. I thought maybe moving the $VAR to my header.php but again it still get reset.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
}else{


    if(isset($_POST['attack'])){

        $health--;

    }

?>

<form action="battlesystem.php" method="post">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="attack" value="Confirm"</td>
            <td><?php echo number_format($health); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <hr />

<?php
}

include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: cookies, sessions or DB. I would advise DB since cookies and sessions can be manipulated.

Comment: Thats what i was afraid of DB it is then.